# Baffling identity: $\prod \log_{10} \tan = \sum \log_{10} \tan$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

I am quite a baffled now, I am not getting by *how* it can be written that :

\begin{align*}
&\log_{10} \tan 40^\circ \cdot \log_{10} \tan 41^\circ \cdot \log_{10} \tan 42^\circ \cdot\log_{10} \tan 43^\circ \cdots \log_{10} \tan 50^\circ  \\
&= \log_{10} \tan 40^\circ + \log_{10} \tan 41^\circ + \log_{10} \tan 42^\circ + \log_{10} \tan 43^\circ + \cdots + \log_{10} \tan 50^\circ 
\end{align*}

Is it even valid ? If yes,how ?

Comment: Are you missing `+` signs in the right hand side?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin :Thanks for the editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is valid.

$\log_{10} \tan 40^{\circ} + \log_{10} \tan 50^{\circ} = \log_{10} \tan 40^{\circ} + \log_{10} \cot 40^{\circ} = \log_{10} 1 = 0$

Similarly combine 41 and 49, 42 and 48 etc.

The product on the left side is $0$ as $\log_{10} \tan 45^{\circ} = 0$.

Comment: That's awesome, btw what is ur age Moron ? 55+ ? :P

Comment: @Deb: Check my profile.

Comment: @Moron:well,I don't remember it to be there last time I checked, ... You are way older than me ;)

Comment: @Deb: Check again :-)

Comment: Okay I got it now ... ! :)

Comment: @Moron:Have you changed your profile since... November?

Comment: @The Chaz: I probably did.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Observe that $$\log_{10} \tan{40} + \log_{10} \tan{50} = \log_{10} \sin{40} - \log_{10} \cos{40} + \log_{10} \sin{50} - \log_{10} \cos{50}$$ Now use the fact that $\sin(90 - x) =\cos{x}$ and see that they cancel out.